# validar un email en nodejs

Tags: nodejs

//Como dice el titulo, estoy tratando de validar un formulario y tengo un problema al querer validar un correo, les dejo el codigo acontinuacion:

```
export const verifiData = (data: IUser )=> {
  let {nombre, apellido, usuario, correo, password, birth} = data
  if (nombre.length == 1 || /^\s+$/.test(nombre)) return {err: 'Ingrese un nombre valido.'}
  if (apellido.length <= 2 || /^\s+$/.test(apellido)) return {err: 'Ingrese un apellido valido.'}
  if (usuario.length <= 5) return {err: 'Su nombre de usuario debe tener al menos 5 caracteres.'}
  if (password.length <= 5 ) return {err: 'Su contraseña debe tener al menos 6 caracteres.'}
  if (/\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)/.test(correo)) return {err: 'El correo ingresado es invalido, ingrese su correo original.'}
  if (birth == null ) return {err: 'Ingrese su fecha de nacimiento.'}
  if (usuario.charAt(0) != "@"){
      let user = "@" + usuario
      let data = {nombre, apellido, user, correo, password, birth}
      return {success: 'Se registro correctamente', datos: data}
  }else{
      return {success: 'Se registro correctamente', datos: data}
  }
 }
```

este codigo se encuentra en una carpeta llamada `functions` donde almaceno funciones ara utilizar en algunas ocaciones, lo que trae por parametro `data` esta funcion es simplemente datos del formulario, a la hora de querer comprar el email no lo hace y no se por que, me pueden ayudar? muchas gracias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disto mucho de ser experto en [Expresiones Regulares](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expresi%C3%B3n_regular) sin embargo, como todo programador en algún momento me he tenido que aventurar a escribir patrones de búsqueda usando las mismas.

A veces el problema de las expresiones regulares es que se vuelven complejas y densas de acuerdo al tipo de patrón que deseamos validar.

El patrón para validar un correo electrónico usando expresiones regulares puede ser bastante complejo si se desea tener algo medianamente fiable.

Tu expresión regular falla por algunos motivos bastante interesantes.

Veamos:

```js
const regex = /\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)/;
const correos = [
  {valid: true, correo: 'user@email.com'},
  {valid: true, correo: 'user-1@email-2.com'},
  {valid: true, correo: '123@456.com'},
  {valid: true, correo: 'user.name@email.com'},
  {valid: true, correo: 'user@sub.email.com'},
  {valid: true, correo: 'user+name@email.com'},
  {valid: false, correo: 'user@name@email.com'},
  {valid: false, correo: 'user@email'},
  {valid: false, correo: '@email.com'},
  {valid: false, correo: '@user'}
];

correos.forEach(correo => {
  console.log(`valid: ${correo.valid}, test: ${regex.test(correo.correo)}`);
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Como puedes ver, de la lista de correos hay 6 válidos y 4 inválidos y tu expresión regular falla 4 de 10 veces en detectar si un correo tiene un formato correcto.

Pero, ¿cuál es el formato correcto de un correo?

Según la [RFC 2821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821) y la [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) las direcciones de correo pueden contener solamente caracteres [ASCII](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) de 7 bits.

Adicionalmente la [RFC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments) 2822 establece en su sección [3.4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.4.1) la especificación de correo electrónico como:

```
addr-spec       =       local-part "@" domain

local-part      =       dot-atom / quoted-string / obs-local-part

domain          =       dot-atom / domain-literal / obs-domain
```

De los tipos de estructuras que se mencionan en la documentación la más usual es [`dot-atom`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.2.4).

La definición es bastante clara en cuanto al tipo de caracteres que conforman una estructura tipo `dot-atom`:

```
atext           =       ALPHA / DIGIT / ; Any character except controls,
                        "!" / "#" /     ;  SP, and specials.
                        "$" / "%" /     ;  Used for atoms
                        "&" / "'" /
                        "*" / "+" /
                        "-" / "/" /
                        "=" / "?" /
                        "^" / "_" /
                        "`" / "{" /
                        "|" / "}" /
                        "~"
```

Traducción propia:

> Tanto un `atom` como un `dot-atom` se interpretan como una unidad simple compuesta por la cadena de caracteres que la construyen. ... ; el *atom* es sólo la serie de caracteres `atext` en un atom, o la serie de caracteres `atext` acompañados de caracteres "." en un `dot-atom`.

Ahora, si bien hay caracteres que están permitidos, por lo general y para evitar confusión se evita su uso.

Mi respuesta no ahondará en la decisión de usar o no ciertos caracteres en las direcciones de correo. Eso es otro asunto muy diferente y siempre debatible.

Puedes consultar el siguiente [enlace](https://www.jochentopf.com/email/chars.html) donde se da una guía orientativa sobre el uso o no de ciertos caracteres para direcciones de correo electrónico.

En cuanto a tu expresión regular, tratemos de analizarla un momento.

1. Para tu `local-part` tienes la siguiente estructura: `\w+([-+.']\w+)*`.

- `\w+` => Cualquier carácter alfanumérico en cantidad de 1 o más.
- `([-+.']\w+)` => Grupo de captura para el conjunto de caracteres: `+ - . '` y cualquier carácter alfanumérico que se repita 1 o más veces.

Claramente esta expresión regular no funciona para lo que necesitamos hacer, ya que obliga a que todo correo tenga uno de los caracteres dentro de los corchetes y caracteres alfanuméricos después.

Podríamos analizar la segunda parte (la referente a `domain`) pero no vale la pena.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Esta solución parte de una premisa: *no reinventes la rueda*. Si, como te imaginarás, no eres el primero ni el único programador que ha necesitado validar un correo electrónico usando una expresión regular. Por lo tanto, debes apoyarte en el camino ya transitado por otros que han pasado antes que tú.

Yo utilizo la siguiente expresión regular:

```
/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

¿Compleja verdad?

No es mía, ni quiero los créditos por la misma.

Existe una página: [emailregex.com](https://emailregex.com/) que nos ayuda a probar nuestras expresiones regulares y adicionalmente nos provee de las mismas para validar correos con una exactitud del 99.99% (según la misma página, y no lo pongo en duda).

Entonces, lo que te sugiero hacer es usar dicha expresión regular de Javascript para que valides correctamente los correos electrónicos en tu aplicación.

**P.D.**

En dicha página también ofrecen expresiones regulares basadas en otros lenguajes populares.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo, leeré sobre el tema en los links que me dejaste, siempre es bueno aprender cosas nuevas, de verdad muchísimas gracias, que tengas buen día