# ¿Cómo obtener un email con una expresión regular?

Tags: javascript, regex

Recién estoy aprendiendo a utilizar las expresiones regulares, y en este caso deseo hacer check con los emails.

Lo que deseo es poder hacer check si el correo es "correo@correo.com" o si el dominio tiene alguna extensión como "correo@correo.com.co".

De momento he podido lograr esto:

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*/g
```

Funciona a medias. La expresión NO hace check si solo se escribe el punto sin el dominio: "correo@correo." Ese resultado es el deseado, pues hace check solo si se escriben letras después del punto: "correo@correo.com".

El problema es que si se escribe el dominio junto con el punto de la extensión, pero SIN la extensión, también hace check. Es decir, si se escribe esto: "correo@correo.com." haría check, y lo que deseo es que no haga check si hay un punto "suelto" o "huérfano" sin ningún dominio, al igual que en el caso anterior.

De antemano lamento si resulta un poco difícil de entender y también haber repetido tantas veces "check". Agradezco mucho cualquier ayuda.

PD: uso JavaScript.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [validar un email en nodejs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/352026/validar-un-email-en-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

A lo mejor [esa respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/4068129) te inspira

Intuyo que no te sirve la validacion de [campo email de un input en html5](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_email.asp)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero te invito a leer [answer]. Responder sólo con un enlace se considera de baja calidad. Por otro lado, esa pregunta ya la han realizado antes en el sitio (como tu mismo sugieres), motivo por el cual terminará cerrada. Cuando tengas la [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) suficiente podrás dejar [comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) en cualquier publicación. Saludos