# ¿Cómo validar dirección de correo electrónico con expresión regular?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Necesitó construir una expresión regular para validar direcciones de correo, el problema que tengo es que direcciones como estas las devuelve

```
efrain.mejias@tec.inovacion
efrain@admin
efrain@asm.tecnologia
```

Tengo este código pero no me funciona para estos formatos, esta devolviendo como no validos y deberia devolverlos validos.

```
public static bool ValidarDireccion(string Direccion)
{
    if (Information.IsNothing(Direccion) || Direccion.Length <= 0)
        return false;
    else
        return Regex.IsMatch(Direccion, @"/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/");
}
```

Comment: Dices que `efrain.mejias@tec.inovacion` es un email válido? No termina en ningún top-level domain (com, net, co, mx, info, me,...)

Comment: No me manejo en expresiones regulares, así que no puedo darte una solución por ese lado, pero podrías ocupar dataanotations [EmailAddress]

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [validar un email en nodejs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/352026/validar-un-email-en-nodejs)

Comment: @Alfabravo, no todos los correos electrónicos *deben* terminar en un `top-level` nivel, sin embargo, buena apreciación por tu parte. Por otro lado, si el dominio de Internet al que pertenece dicha dirección está registrado así, tampoco habría problema con dicha dirección de correo.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Validar un email en JavaScript que acepte todos los caracteres latinos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/142/validar-un-email-en-javascript-que-acepte-todos-los-caracteres-latinos)

Comment: Intenta con esto ^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-]))+(\.{0,2})+([a-zA-Z0-9])  Puedes probar expresiones regulares en sitios online como este [RegExr](https://regexr.com/)